# I am editing codelabs freindly chat app web. i do not want the sign in function how to remove that

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, chat, google-codelab

I am editing codelabs freindly chat app web. i do not want the sign in function how to remove that

source code on https://github.com/firebase/codelab-friendlychat-web folder web

Comment: Copy the code into the question. See [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: if i copy it showing the error there is only code in your post  my code is same as in that github"s link web folder please check it